# Where does the equation $p=\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{T^2 +2mTc^2}$ come from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum, mass-energy

Where does the relativistic formula

$$p~=~\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{T^2 +2mTc^2}$$

come from? What is the derivation from Einstein's formula? $T$ is the kinetic energy $m$ is the mass $p$ is the momentum.

Comment: Can you add a bit more context? what is $T$ here?

Comment: Some more context on *where* you saw this equation would be better as well.

Comment: In /gamma decay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write total energy $E$ two ways:
\begin{equation} 
E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4 \\
E=T+mc^2, 
\end{equation} 
where $T$ is kinetic energy. 
Eliminating $E$ from those two equations will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $T = E - E_0 =  m\gamma c^2 - mc^2 = mc^2(\gamma -1)$ and $p = |\vec p| = m\gamma |\vec v| = m\gamma v$